# How to run a function when a checkbox is checked and unchecked in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen various questions here, but they are of ng-checked, which are not relevant to me I guess. I have a fairly simple problem. Here's my HTML.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-checked="dothis" id="alcohol">Serves alcohol</label>
```

I am not sure how to wrap the function in angular if its checked. Basically it should be like.

```
if(checked){
//do this
}
else{
//do that
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngModel` to bind the value two way.

While `ngChange` is an optional.

Please find the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Please find the working demo below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-app="checkboxExample" name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
   </label><br/>
  <tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel.value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>value2 = {{checkboxModel.value2}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `ngModel` and `ngChange`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo" ng-change="fooChanged()" />

//in controller
$scope.foo = false;
$scope.fooChanged = function(){
    if($scope.foo){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ajiaz, you're welcome, could you mark it as answer?